# Play involving a writer being questioned by the police after children start dying in a way matching his stories

Tags: identification-request, theater

When I was in grad school at Carnegie Mellon University, around 2007-2009, I went to a play audition where the piece they had me reading involved a writer (Russian?) being interrogated by the police because some children have been found murdered in a manner similar to the contents of his stories. The excerpt I read for the audition (I didn't get in) had a story mentioned involving little men made out of apples who either had razor blades inside of them, or wielded razors, with the girl found cut up and posed with, well, little men fashioned out of apples with razor blades. The writer doesn't know who might be doing the killing, and the police are trying to get him to confess by claiming that his brother (mentally disabled?) will be tortured or made the scapegoat if the writer does not confess. I remember it as that the writer was genuinely not certain if someone was doing the killings after being inspired by his books, or if perhaps something has made his stories come true.

I've tried looking at CMU seasons online for 2007-2009, but I don't see anything that matches up with my memories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pillowman):

> The Pillowman is a 2003 play by British-Irish playwright Martin
> McDonagh.
>
> Katurian, a writer of short stories that often depict violence against
> children, has been arrested by two detectives, Ariel and Tupolski,
> because some of his stories resemble recent child murders.
>
> Katurian's brother, who is "slow to get things" following his years of
> abuse at the hands of his parents
>
> **"The Little Apple Men"** Told briefly in I.i, and re-enacted in the first child murder. A young girl, whose father mistreats her, carves a
> set of little men out of apples. She gives them to her father, telling
> him to save them rather than eat them. He scoffs at her, and eats
> several. The apple has razor blades inside, which kill the father. At
> night the remaining apple men accuse the girl of killing their
> brothers, and jump down her throat to kill her

**How the answer was found**: I've read the play several years ago, it's hard to forget! It's a cool play (if you OK with violence).

Comment: In retrospect, searching for `play "apple men" razors` brings it up as the first result, although `play apple men razors` does not.